# Add description to each dropdown options dynamically in Django-widget-tweaks form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have this form select dropdown, rendered using Django-tweak's `render_field`.
In my template, I have this form like so:

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="org-member-edit" id='organization_permissions' data-parsley-validate>

    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group member-role{% if org_role_form.org_role.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">

        <label class="control-label" for="{{ org_role_form.org_role.id_for_label }}">{% trans "Role" %}</label>

    {% render_field org_role_form.org_role class+="form-control" data-parsley-required="true" %}

        <div class="error-block">{{ org_role_form.org_role.errors }}</div>

   </div>

</form>
```

in the 5th line above, i.e the `render_field org_role_form.org_role` in the template tag, the `org_role` takes up values from the following form:

```
class EditOrganizationMemberForm(SuperUserCheck, forms.Form):

    org_role = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ADMIN_CHOICES)
```

which takes choice fields from another file choices.py like so:

```
ADMIN_CHOICES = (
             ('A', _('Administrator')),
             ('M', _('Member'))
            )
```

and so the dropdown looks like:

[image]

I want it to look something like this:

[image]

When I inspect the element (dev tools in browser), I can see that this select option gets rendered up like this:

[image]

so, I tried attempting for the solution using jQuery like so:

```
$('#id_org_role option').each( function(){
  if ($(this).val() == 'M') {
    $(this).text().append("<br/> description here");
  }
  else if ($(this).val() == 'A'){
    $(this).text().append("<br/> description here");
  }
});
```

But it didnt help. however, If I do:

```
$('#id_org_role option').each( function(){
  if ($(this).val() == 'M') {
    alert($(this).val());
  }
});
```

it works,and generates an alert with value 'M' which means the code is running correclty till and after `if statement` but for appending the text, it doesn't work.

I am really stuck. please help.

Comment: You won't be able to get that kind of layout using a standard `option` element. To do what you require you'd need to convert the `select` and its `option` elements to other HTML which can be styled. There are third party libraries which can do this for you already, such as Select2

Comment: I am actually contributing to open source and this is the part of the open source project. So I have to follow their architecture. I can integrate something different just to implement this. Please guide if there can be any other solution to this. Thanks @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I just realised that the org itself uses select2 and that's perfect. Thanks a lot for helping. I might consider using it over here, and will get back to you if I get stuck. I would be great if you could help me then too. Thanks for the suggestion anyway. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan unfortunately, I couldn't get any solution to this anywhere. I am really stuck at this problem since hours. Please help me.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan finally resolved the issue. Thanks for suggesting for select2 anyway. It worked great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's how I resolved the whole thing using jquery-select2 as suggested by Rory in the comments:

First, include all the necessary select2 files inside the template:

```
{% block extra_head %}
<link href="https://select2.github.io/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://select2.github.io/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://select2.github.io/css/s2-docs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_script %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://select2.github.io/vendor/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://select2.github.io/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://select2.github.io/vendor/js/prettify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://select2.github.io/vendor/js/anchor.min.js"></script>
```

then inside the JavaScript block above, under the last file included, add the following jQuery to define a width and add a title attribute for each option like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('select').each(function(){
    $(this).css('width','250px');
  }); //give a width to each dropdown.

  $('select option').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() === 'M'){
      $(this).attr('title','Members can view all the public projects in the organization. Additional permissions are assigned on a project level.');
    }
    else if ($(this).val() === 'A') {
      $(this).attr('title','Administrators have full access to all organizational details and projects.');
    }
    else if ($(this).val() === 'Pb') {
      $(this).attr('title','Members can view all public project data.');
    }
    else if ($(this).val() === 'PU') {
      $(this).attr('title','Members can view both public and private project data.');
    }
    else if ($(this).val() === 'DC') {
      $(this).attr('title','Members can access all project data and upload any field data.');
    }
    else if ($(this).val() === 'PM') {
      $(this).attr('title','Members can edit all project data.');
    }
  }); // add title attributes for each dropdown option.
```

Then include the Select2 code to add the description for each option under the above jQuery code like so:

```
function formatOption (option) {
  var $option = $(
    '<div><strong>' + option.text + '</strong></div><div>' + option.title + '</div>' 
// takes each option's title, and makes it appear as description just below it.
  );
  return $option;
};

$("select").select2({
  templateResult: formatOption,
  minimumResultsForSearch: -1 // hides the default select2 search bar
});
```

then close the extra_script block tag:

```
{% endblock %}
```

and that's all.